# Kill Process like Task Manager (Windows 8) do, because of access denied

Tags: c#, process, kill, taskmanager, win32-process

I have the following problem:
I try to Kill a Process of a Online Game from c# code. I always get "access denied"! It has an Anti Hack Shield, I think that's the problem...

**[Edit]**
I added /T to the TaskKill Commandline and get now the Error child Process with PID "access denied".
I can not find this PID neither in Process.GetProcessById() nor in the Threads List of the Main Process.. Someone know how to Find this?

But with the Window Task Manager I can kill it!
I get my Process by finding the Window with P/invoke FindWindow() and GetWindowThreadProcessId() 
I checked the PID it is the same! 
I use the P/Invoke because I need it anyway for SetFourgroundWindow()

I also found this active in kernel mode[1] it's an online game so its using the network adapter, can this be the problem? but why I can kill it with Task manager?
In this case I find the SetKernelObjectSecurity: http://csharptest.net/coding/ I'm not sure if I did it right I just changed AceQualifier.AccessDenied to AccessAllowed not working.

So how can I Kill it the same way as the Task Manager do?
Or can I call the Method of the Task Manager?
Maybe I need to change some Parameter/ Rights before?

I searched and I find something with SeDebugPrivilege: [2] I used it but still the same "access denied" I also tried it with Process.EnterDebugMode();

That’s my ways I tried: I run Visual Studio as administrator

```
public void KillKal(IntPtr _WindowPointer)
{
    uint ProcessID;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(_WindowPointer, out ProcessID);
    try
    {
        #region SeDebugPrivilege 
        IntPtr hToken;
        LUID luidSEDebugNameValue;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkpPrivileges;

        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, out hToken))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() failed, error = {0} . SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OpenProcessToken() successfully");
        }

        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_DEBUG_NAME, out luidSEDebugNameValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() successfully");
        }

        tkpPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tkpPrivileges.Luid = luidSEDebugNameValue;
        tkpPrivileges.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, ref tkpPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LookupPrivilegeValue() failed, error = {0} .SeDebugPrivilege is not available", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SeDebugPrivilege is now available");
        }

        Process.EnterDebugMode();
        #endregion SeDebugPrivilege
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)ProcessID);

        //1. try
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = string.Format("/c taskkill /pid {0} /f", ProcessID)
        });
        //2.try
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "net.exe",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = string.Format("stop {0}", p.ProcessName)
        });
        //3. try
        Process.Start("cmd", string.Format("/c \"taskkill /f /pid {0}\"", ProcessID));

        //4. try get exception: access denided
        p.Kill();

        //5. try get exception:Process must exit before requested information can be determined.
        TerminateProcess(p.Handle, (uint)p.ExitCode);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I also tried with PsKill and task kill in administration cmd ! https://postimg.org/image/qp5nkjvtn/

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038165/kill-process-windows-8-issues

[2] http://hintdesk.com/c-how-to-enable-sedebugprivilege/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement that this way you must be running VS as Administrator, and this should be run

```
Process.Start("cmd", string.Format("/c \"taskkill /f /pid {0}\"", ProcessID));
```

as administrator also.

You should use `ProcessStartInfo` class to run command like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = true;
//The magic happens here
info.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(info);
```

**Edit**

You must also kill child processes, so the parameters of the `taskkill` command should be: `taskkill /T /F /pid {0}`

Comment: Tanks you right with the cmd. But as you can see here its still not working  http://postimg.org/image/qp5nkjvtn/

Comment: Thank you. You were right the problem is a child Process. But know i get the Error child Process with PID "access denied". I can not find this PID neither in Process.GetProcessById() nor in the Threads List of the Main Process.. Do you know a way to track this Process? I will add this to my Question.

Comment: @StefanErler if you are still getting access denied then it is likely that even though you ***think*** you are running your program as administrator you are not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I run VisualStudio as Administrator as you can see here http://postimg.org/image/trok06ia7/ . I also tried to run the release file AS Administrator. And i killed Winrar.exe successfully. So i think I’m in Admin mode.

Comment: Sory, i have missed your reply. I'll try to answer in about 6-7 hours (when will be at home). Thank you for patience, our flight continues :)